# Searching for favorites in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-search

Earlier versions of Windows had intimate knowledge of IE favorites. In particular, the file "search" feature (under the Windows start button) knew about IE favorites and allowed me to search for them.

This doesn't seem to work in Windows 10. I can "import" my old IE favorites into Edge (or Chrome or whatever), but Windows Search (click the Start button and start typing) no longer finds any of my favorites.

Am I just missing something?  Is there a way to tell Windows 10 to include my favorites in the search results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you're not missing anything....  That feature clearly does not exist yet.

This is a known issue, and there is a lot of requests for this feature (via the Windows feedback tool), however the current builds available to the Windows Insiders do not yet support it.  So, that means that this feature will probably not make it into the Anniversary Update to Windows 10 that is expected in July

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I solved Windows 10's inability to manage/search my Favorites.  I opened Chrome and imported my favorites into Chrome.  It's not that hard, so I won't attempt to describe the process. You may want to go to this website and learn how to manage your bookmarks/favorites.  https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/188842?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en

Comment: I don't get it. How does this help me search for favorites from the Windows Start button?